# gfortran not working on osx yosemite

Tags: fortran, osx-yosemite, gfortran

I recently installed fortran on my Macbook Pro mid 2011 that is running OS X Yosemite.  When I try to compile code, I get this:

`gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.0.0 ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that Mac OS X's headers are not C99/C++98 compatible.
See bug 61407 at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61407.  That bug report provides a patch.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Xcode command line tools as described at http://hpc.sourceforge.net
I also installed full gcc binary for Yosemite from http://hpc.sourceforge.net
Seemed to solve this problem.
JTN

Answer (score 0):

Install the 5.0 version of gcc and/or gfortran from http://hpc.sourceforge.net
Works perfectly for OS X Yosemite